# Using LeCos- QGIS crashing

Tags: qgis, landscape, fragstats

I have a raster of forest and non-forest data. I am trying to analyse it using LeCos on QGIS. The pixel size is equivalent to 1sq.m and there class information ranges from 1-503. When I load it into LeCos it doesnt generate any information and QGIS stops functioning. Could someone guide me as to how I can work with LeCos and prevent the software from crashing?

Comment: try https://peerj.com/preprints/116.pdf? or contact the plugin creator - what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you :)